# How can post a xml to an API get way by RestEase?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webapi

I did a research in the official page of the [RestEase](https://github.com/canton7/RestEase#installation) but I don't find a way to post a xml data to a Web API controller.
Is any one have experience to do it?
thank you very much

Comment: Which bit specifically are you having trouble with? There are examples in the README for posting data, and for writing a custom serialize which formats data as XML